# Angular: @HostListener('window:onunload', ['$event']) does not work when used in base abstract class

Tags: angular

I want to have abstract class component that would wrap 'window:onunload' events. I have the following abstract class:

```
@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class WindowUnloadComponent {    

    @HostListener('window:onunload', ['$event'])
    public onUnload($event: Event) {        

        this.onWindowUnloadAction();
    }
    
    public abstract onWindowUnloadAction(): void;
}
```

And the component that extends it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',    
})
export class MyComponent extends WindowUnloadComponent {
public onWindowUnloadAction() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

But the actual code in *onWindowUnloadAction()* does not hit on browser close. If I put **@HostListener('window:onunload', ['$event'])** inside the child class all is fine.
Have I missed something?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need an `abstract` class here?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you have to annotate your abstract base class with `@Directive()` instead of `@Component()`.